# Rails: Use helper_method from one controller in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have the following controller:

```
class FirstController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :contoller_method

private 
  def contoller_method
    "text"
  end
end
```

How can I use `contoller_method` in the view of another controller? Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Place the method in the `application_controller.rb`. Then it'll be available to all your controllers.

If you only wanted to share it between two classes you could do something like this. Create a new controller called helper controller and have the First/Second controller inherit from it.

```
class FirstController < HelperController

end

class SecondController < HelperController

end

class HelperController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :contoller_method

  private 
    def contoller_method
      "text"
    end
end
```

Comment: It is an option :) Thank you. But can I share this method only between two controllers?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this?

```
class FirstController
  include SomeConcern
end

class SecondController
  include SomeConcern
end

module SomeConcern
  def self.included(base)
    base.helper_method :controller_method
  end

  private 

  def controller_method
    "text"
  end
end
```